# Vietnamese Children recordings

Tags: field, recordings

I've been commissioned to work on a soundscape to accompany a art installation/theatre performance to celebrate 150 years of the Red Cross. I've been asked to recreate the sonic ambience of a refugee camp where masses of Vietnamese families fled to during the mid-70's onwards.

I'm struggling to source recordings of Vietnamese children, of which there were thousands, held in these camps. I've found some recordings by Rob Nokes at Sounddogs of school children in Vietnam but this is all I can find in any libraries around.

Would anybody be able to help me with any recordings they may have or can point me in the right direction? We do have a small budget or I'm happy to swap some of my personal library with you.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a recording I made in Hue, Vietnam of a group of middle school aged kids playing/rough housing in a public park after school. Would be happy to send it your way if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have some recordings of Cambodian children playing if that could possibly work? I'm not sure if their languages are sonically simiallar at all but at a guess they may be. Depending how loud u have it in the mix and how accurate it needs to be it could work for you.

Comment: I'm sure they sound pretty similar as a Westerner but I would be concerned on they weren't at least in the same language. Thanks for your offer...

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine just got back from a trip to Vietnam, and he shot a lot of film footage for travel videos he makes. I will ask if he has any sounds that might help you, and I can maybe put you in touch with him if it looks like that's the case.

Comment: I asked him, and he said that unfortunately he doesn't have anything that would fit the bill. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, recording audio in VN is relatively difficult: there are by far too many motorbikes contaminating any recording. A good friend of mine is in VN at the moment and will start traveling around within the coming two weeks. If it's not too late for you and you still need recordings I could ask him if he could send something over.
Let me know ;) (suzanne.soundcreations@gmail.com)